# PHP Intl SpoofChecker::isSuspicious() yields false positive

Tags: php, intl

**Case**

It seems that [`Spoofchecker`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spoofchecker.php) from the [`Intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extention yields false positives:

```
<?php  // 7.0 on linux
// File encoding of this script is UTF-8 (thus without BOM)
$sDefaultLocale = (new \Locale)->getDefault();
$oSpoofchecker = new \Spoofchecker;
$oSpoofchecker->setAllowedLocales($sDefaultLocale);
$sText = 'abc';  // US-ASCII
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
print
    'Default locale: ' . $sDefaultLocale . PHP_EOL
  . 'Byte length: ' . strlen($sText) . PHP_EOL  // US-ASCII check
  . 'Text "' . $sText . '" '
  . ($oSpoofchecker->isSuspicious($sText, $sError) ? 'IS' : 'IS NOT')
  . ' suspicious' . PHP_EOL
  . 'Spoofchecker internal error information:' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($sError);
```

**Results**

```
Default locale: en_US_POSIX
Byte length: 3
Text "abc" IS suspicious
Spoofchecker internal error information:
NULL
```

**Expected results**

```
Text "abc" IS NOT suspicious
```

This is because abc is US-ASCII which *assumably* should be the default for `en_US_POSIX`. Also [PHP Spoofchecker class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458876/php-spoofchecker-class) mentions that the return code of `Spoofchecker::isSuspicious()` would be `TRUE` if any non-English characters are used, which is not the case here.

**Possible causes**

The [documentation of `Spoofchecker::setAllowedLocales()`](http://php.net/manual/en/spoofchecker.setallowedlocales.php) is currently close to non-existent, the argument list does not contain a list of possible values. One can only *assume* that it must be compatible with that of [`Locale`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php). The documentation reads:

> Locales are identified using RFC 4646 language tags (which use hyphen, not underscore)

contradicts the test result where `Locale` uses underscores for the default locale instead of hyphens. But when running another test with `$oSpoofchecker->setAllowedLocales('en-US');` the results stay the same.

**Question**

How to use `Spoofchecker::isSuspicious()` properly?

Comment: Why is 'abc' US-ASCII if your file encoding is UTF-8? Have you made sure it is **really** UTF-8

Comment: US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. To double check I replaced `$sText = 'abc';` with `$sText = chr(97) . chr(98) . chr(99);` which unfortunately did not change the result. And I double checked both visually with an UTF-8 string and I checked the settings of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's Intl extension is just a wrapper around [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), whose Spoofchecker received a reduction in false positives starting with ICU version 58.

From their [bug tracker](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/12549#comment:10):

> ICU 58 reflects the latest Unicode update, which deprecates the
>   Whole-Script Confusables (WSC) check and Mixed-Script Confusables
>   (MSC) check and is available at
>   ​http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2016/16229-revising-uts-39-algorithm.pdf.
>
> Under ICU 57, the checks (WSC and MSC) had the following pitfalls:
>
> 1. **They did not restrict themselves to the set of characters specified by
>      SpoofChecker#setAllowedChars or SpoofChecker#setAllowedLocales.**
> 2. They did not correctly handle confusables containing multiple skeleton
>      characters, like 'æ' to 'ae'.
> 3. **WSC exhibited a high false-positive
>      rate, especially as more and more entries were being added to
>      confusables.txt.**
> 4. All strings failing MSC also fail Restriction Level.
>      (Your string, "goօgle", is an example.)
>
> With these pitfalls in mind,
>   WSC and MSC were removed from ICU 58.

Emphasis mine. The WSC check is what your string is [failing](https://3v4l.org/9Q5Zo). (Note that it passes where ICU version is 58.1 and up as that check has been removed entirely.)

As to how to use Spoofchecker::isSuspicious() properly:

1. Upgrade ICU (which is a good idea in general) or
2. Use  `Spoofchecker::setChecks()` as noted in [Syscall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823825/3942918) and omit the WSC check `Spoofchecker::WHOLE_SCRIPT_CONFUSABLE` (which covers this case) and the MSC check `Spoofchecker::MIXED_SCRIPT_CONFUSABLE` (which is likewise removed from recent versions.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Spoofchecker::setChecks(int $checks)`](http://php.net/manual/en/spoofchecker.setchecks.php) to specify how the string will be verified.

The `$checks` constants are listed in the Spoofchecker class [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spoofchecker.php), and described by a user [in comments](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spoofchecker.php#121142).

You can use `SpoofChecker::CHAR_LIMIT` (or a combination of multiple constants, eg: `SpoofChecker::CHAR_LIMIT|Spoofchecker::INVISIBLE`):

> `CHAR_LIMIT`: Check that an identifier contains only characters from a specified set of acceptable characters.
>   `INVISIBLE`: Check an identifier for the presence of invisible characters, such as zero-width spaces, or character sequences that are likely not to display, such as multiple occurrences of the same non-spacing mark.

```
$sDefaultLocale = (new \Locale)->getDefault();
$oSpoofchecker = new \Spoofchecker;
$oSpoofchecker->setAllowedLocales($sDefaultLocale);
$oSpoofchecker->setChecks(SpoofChecker::CHAR_LIMIT);
$sText = 'abc';  // US-ASCII
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
print
    'Default locale: ' . $sDefaultLocale . PHP_EOL
  . 'Byte length: ' . strlen($sText) . PHP_EOL  // US-ASCII check
  . 'Text "' . $sText . '" '
  . ($oSpoofchecker->isSuspicious($sText, $sError) ? 'IS' : 'IS NOT')
  . ' suspicious' . PHP_EOL
  . 'Spoofchecker internal error information:' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($sError);
```

Will outputs:

```
Default locale: en_US_POSIX
Byte length: 3
Text "abc" IS NOT suspicious
Spoofchecker internal error information:
NULL
```

Using the example from the [`isSuspicious()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/spoofchecker.issuspicious.php), the text `Рaypal.com` (with first letter is from Cyrylic), the method with returns:

```
Text "Рaypal.com" IS suspicious
```